# Selecting Overlapping Clusters with certain threshold

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis, threshold, nonlinear-optimization

Say, I have done clustering on my dataset and have 10 clusters. These clusters are non-overlapping. But now assume I changed some feature in all my data points and do clustering again. Now I have 10 more clusters. If I repeat it say 3 more times, at the end I would have 50 clusters. Each cluster has a score associated with it that is calculated from its constituents data points.

These 50 clusters now have overlapping data points. I want to select all possible clusters out of these 50 clusters that have a certain threshold of overlap allowed, to get the highest total score of selected clusters.

One way is a greedy method where I sort the clusters based on the score from highest to smallest. Then select highest scoring cluster. Then from there keep selecting clusters that have overlap within threshold with already selected clusters. But it doesn't seem to be optimal solution although it is fast.

Example: say I have 3 clusters with following scores:

C1 = (A,B,C,D,E,F) Score = 10

C2 = (A,B,C,D) Score = 6

C3 = (D,E,F) Score = 6

Overlap allowed is 1 element or less than 40% of the size of the smaller cluster.

The greedy approach will return {C1} with a total score of 10, whereas better option is {C2, C3} with a total score of 6+6=12, with an overlap of element 'D', i.e. 1/size(C3) = 1/3 = 33.33% < 40%

I am looking for another method that can give an optimal solution or better solution than above mentioned greedy approach.

Comment: How many clusters and how many data points are we talking about?

Comment: Have you tried using a generic optimizer? If you have just 50 clusters, you can afford this.

Comment: @juvian In my problem, the number of clusters increases after every iteration. It starts at 20 and then 20 more are added after each iteration. And I need to select overlapping clusters as defined before in each iteration. So I will do with I have 20 clusters, then in 2nd iteration with 40 clusters, then 3rd iteration with 60 clusters..... Up to 400 or 600 iterations.
Total data points can be 50,000 also.

Comment: Okay sounds like too much data for an optimal solution. Can't think of a better greedy, could try with heuristic algorithms like taboo search or genetic algorithm

Comment: Genetic algorithm could work... but still looking for other methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the unconstrained version of your problem is given in the following link:
[Selecting non-overlapping best quality clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263975/selecting-non-overlapping-best-quality-clusters/50299976#50299976)

You can add new constraints, in the model coded in the above link, for checking the overlapping between the selected clusters and restricting it by the allowed threshold value.

Here is the python code for the above problem:

```
from gurobipy import *
import string
# List of all subtomograms
data_points = string.ascii_uppercase[:6]
data_points = list(data_points)

# Clusters as list of lists, where each list is list of subtomograms
clusters = []
clusters.append(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
clusters.append(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
clusters.append(['D', 'E', 'F'])

# Create a matrix: num_subtomograms x num_clusters
matrix = {}
for dp in data_points:
    matrix[dp] = [0]*len(clusters)

# Make matrix[subtomogram_i][cluster_i] = 1, if subtomogram_i is present in cluster_i
for i in range(0, len(clusters)):
    for dp in clusters[i]:
        matrix[dp][i] = 1

# Score of each cluster in the same order as used in matrix
cost = [10, 6, 6]

# Gurobi MIP model
m = Model("Cluster selection optimization")
m.params.outputflag = 1
m.params.method = 2 # for barrier method in Gurobi, it is used to solve quadratic programming problems

# Adding a variable x where x[i] will represent whether or not ith cluster is selected or not
x = m.addVars(len(clusters), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='x')

# generate objective function: score[0]x[0] + score[1]x[1] .....
indices = range(0, len(clusters))
coef_x = dict()
obj = 0.0
for i in indices:
    coef_x[i] = cost[i]
    obj += coef_x[i] * x[i]
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Generate constraints
threshhold = 0.4 # 40% threshold set
count = 0
m_sum = []
for i in range(len(clusters)):
    m_sum.append(sum([matrix[k][i] for k in data_points]))
for i in range(len(clusters)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(clusters)):
        if i==j:
            continue
        tmp = (sum([matrix[k][i]*matrix[k][j] for k in data_points])*x[i]*x[j] <= threshhold*min(m_sum[i], m_sum[j]))
        m.addConstr(tmp, "C"+str(count))
        count += 1

# Optimize
m.optimize()
print("Optimized")
```

The result and log data of the above run is:

```
Parameter outputflag unchanged
   Value: 1  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 1
Changed value of parameter method to 2
   Prev: -1  Min: -1  Max: 5  Default: -1
Optimize a model with 0 rows, 3 columns and 0 nonzeros
Model has 3 quadratic constraints
Variable types: 0 continuous, 3 integer (3 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  QMatrix range    [1e+00, 4e+00]
  Objective range  [6e+00, 1e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [0e+00, 0e+00]
  QRHS range       [1e+00, 2e+00]
Found heuristic solution: objective -0.0000000
Modified 2 Q diagonals
Modified 2 Q diagonals
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 3 integer (3 binary)
Presolve removed 0 rows and 3 columns
Presolve: All rows and columns removed

Root relaxation: objective 2.200000e+01, 0 iterations, 0.00 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

*    0     0               0      12.0000000   12.00000  0.00%     -    0s

Explored 0 nodes (2 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds
Thread count was 32 (of 32 available processors)

Solution count 2: 12 -0 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.200000000000e+01, best bound 1.200000000000e+01, gap 0.0000%
Optimized
Final Obj: 12.0
1
2
```

There are other methods to solve it such as Artificial Intelligence methods (Hill Climber, Simulated Annealing etc), Evolutionary Optimization methods like Genetic Algorithm (you can use NSGA2 after modifying it according to your problem, code available on http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/codes.shtml)